# Can not run a SSIS package on a bat file, it closes immediately without doing anything

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a bat file that executes a SSIS package through DTEXEC, I already have the code and it runs and executes fine when I open the command prompt and type it directly, but when I execute the bat file, by doing double click on the file, it opens and closes immediately. I want to do it this way because I will execute this file on task scheduler of windows 7(I don't know if that's the right name in English, I speak Spanish). The code is the following.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ "
DTEXEC /FILE "F:\Proyectos\Ind\SSIS Comp\LlenarComp.dtsx" /DECRYPT #81c3 /CHECKPOINTING           OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI >F:\Logs\Log_LlenarComp.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 0 SET ERRORLEV=0
if ERRORLEVEL 1 SET ERRORLEV=1
echo ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEV%
exit /B %ERRORLEV%
echo PS Stage Complete
```

If someone could help me, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: so put a `pause` command at the end so you can see if there's any error messages or whatever when you doubleclick. or run the .bat directly from the command line instead of retyping all of the commands.

Comment: I did that but it stills don't do anything

Comment: well, you do have an exit call, so the script will exit no matter what

Comment: OMG1, you are right, I'm sorry I don't notice it, It works fine now Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `PAUSE` at the end of the .bat file then the command console will stay open and you can see the output/errors.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ "
DTEXEC /FILE "F:\Proyectos\Ind\SSIS Comp\LlenarComp.dtsx" /DECRYPT #81c3 /CHECKPOINTING           OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI >F:\Logs\Log_LlenarComp.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 0 SET ERRORLEV=0
if ERRORLEVEL 1 SET ERRORLEV=1
echo ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEV%
exit /B %ERRORLEV%
echo PS Stage Complete
PAUSE
```

Comment: I did that, but nothing happens, it opens and closes immediately

Comment: I don't know if anything relies on the exit ERRORLEV, however, that is probably halting the script and closing the console.